# throwing an exception and continuing to receive data

Tags: java

In a piece of code I'm currently working on, I'm taking in an `ArrayList` of data to be added to an object, from a user. I'm checking each item in the `ArrayList` against the current list of that type of data for the object, in order to make sure it's not in the list already.

Is there a way to throw an exception for one item in the passed- in list, to tell the user it's in the list already- and then to keep going and add the next items in the passed-in list to my current list if they aren't there already?

Comment: a) Show your code; b) Of course, just catch the exception inside the loop and continue.  Please read some basic tutorials on exceptions and exception handling.

Comment: @JimGarrison OP is trying to *throw* an exception without aborting the method.

Comment: No you cannot do it, throwing an exception forcefully ends the execution of your code. You need to sort this out with some kind of return value for that method.

Comment: @shmosel Catching the exception inside the loop allows you to recover and not terminate the method.  I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: @JimGarrison It's usually pointless to catch an exception if you're the one throwing it.

Comment: Not really, it can be useful sometimes. However using exceptions for what should be flow-control due to laziness (don't bother to validate, let the some code throw for invalid data) is definitely bad code smell.

Answer (score 1):

Update: i solved the problem by surrounding that block of code with a try/catch. Here's my code to clarify:

```
    public void addCategories(ArrayList<BookCategory>categories) {
    boolean exists;

    for(int index = 0; index <categories.size(); index++) {//iterate through passed array list
    try {   
        //for each element, check if it exists in the current category list.
        exists = checkBookCategory(categories.get(index));
        if (exists == false)
        {subjectCategories.add(categories.get(index));}
        else {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Item " + categories.get(index) + " already in list.");         }
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException ie) {
        System.out.println(ie);
    }   }
}
```

Thanks @JimGarrison!

Comment: Is this good coding? or is there a better way than how i did it?

Comment: No, it's bad coding. There's no point in throwing an exception just to catch it immediately. If you want to print an error message, just do that. You don't need an exception in the first place.

Comment: That's what I was going to do originally, but apparently you're not supposed to print error messages (using System.out.println()) from your class, at least according to my programming teacher. I agree that that makes the most sense, but from what I've heard it seems like that is bad coding. Please enlighten me as to whether that's the right way to do things because it would make my life SO much easier.

Comment: That's what you're doing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that yes, you can do this, but it usually is highly discouraged.

Some sample pseudocode:

```
for (Item i : inputList)
{
    try
    {
        myObject.addItem(i);
    } 
    catch (MyCustomDuplicateItemException ex)
    {
        // Tell the user there was a duplicate
    }
}
```

However, this is using exceptions for what should be flow control.  Ideally you would write the `addItem()` method to return a boolean value (i.e. `true`) if the item was successfully added, and the other value (`false`) if the item was a duplicate and NOT throw an exception.